# IModelReadRpcInterface.openForRead() is not available

Tags: imodeljs

The sample simple-viewer-app displays an error related to IModelReadRpcInterface in the browser on after pressing the green Open iModel button

The Chrome browser displays the following in message box:

```
localhost:3000 says
IModelReadRpcInterface.openForRead() is not available
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-cloning the git repository corrected my problem.  My guess is that I may have encountered a problem in a dependent npm package that has subsequently been corrected.